Cryptography Fernet Invalid Token
I am trying in Python Django to create a system for encrypting and decrypting messages. Does anyone know why I get an error every time I try to read a message: "The encrypted message is invalid and cannot be decrypted". Below is my code:
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = BasicUserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        load_dotenv()
        self.ENCRYPTION_KEY = "key_generated_by_fernet.generate_key()"
        self.fernet = Fernet(self.ENCRYPTION_KEY)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['text'] = self.decrypt(instance.text)
        return representation

    def encrypt(self, message):
        encoded_message = message.encode()
        encrypted_message = self.fernet.encrypt(encoded_message)
        return encrypted_message

    def decrypt(self, encrypted_message):
        try:
            decrypted_message = self.fernet.decrypt(encrypted_message)
            decoded_message = decrypted_message.decode()
            return decoded_message
        except InvalidToken:
            raise ValueError("The encrypted message is invalid and cannot be decrypted.")

Has anyone ever had a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

Did you check what value is passed to self.fernet.decrypt?

@maciek97x yes exactly such a message: "b'Z0FBQUFBQm1QZkhCUGhzdmNmaGtaZmVSTUhrQUJYYUVlWEhzRi1kWERaSi1ZckxpVjRSNmRycm9Lc2w1NVlHTkFzVEI0enh6MVF0aExidlJ5bUcxcGQwQVU0czhTRldzNGc9PQ=='"

Not sure why, but it looks like this is encoded using base 64. Try to call it like decrypted_message = self.fernet.decrypt(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encrypted_message))

The code is not executable. If everything unnecessary is removed from the Meta class so that the code is executable, and consistent test data is used, encryption and decryption work on my machine. Change your code to an MCVE, i.e. post an executable code, additionally the calling code and non-productive test data, so that a repro is possible!

@maciek97x still same error: ‚encrypted_message_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(encrypted_message)
decrypted_message = self.fernet.decrypt(encrypted_message_bytes)’

Can you add full traceback?

The posted code seems to work, s. online: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/12hw. Please complete your post so that the issue can be reproduced.

@Topaco First I add the message using the post method and the message is added to the database normally and is encrypted, but then I try to get the message using the get method and decrypt it and then I get this error

Since the code works, the problem is probably related to the data. Possibly the ciphertext is corrupted during transport or when storing in the DB. Log ciphertext (and key) during encryption and decryption and compare whether ciphertext (and key) during decryption correspond to those during encryption.

@Topaco managed to solve the problem, the problem was that django by default additionally converts the text into bytes when saving, so when encrypting it was enough to add:
decoded_message = encrypted_message.decode('utf-8')         return decoded_message
thanks for your help
